# Inflating several same layouts with diffrent data

Tags: android, layout-inflater

How can I inflate several same layouts with diffrent texts and images? I tried use this code

```
    for (final Tour t : info.tours) {
        final LinearLayout list = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tours_list);
        Log.d(Const.LOG_TAG, "Add child view to tours_list");
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tour_item_for_guide_info,
                list, true);
        final ImageView tourImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tour_image);
        final String tourImgUrl = Const.HOST + t.image;
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(tourImgUrl, tourImage);
        TextView tourText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        tourText.setText(t.name);
    }
```

but text and image setted in first inflated layout, replacing the previous text and image. I understand what it's happens because layouts have same ids. Can I resolve it? I know about ListView and adapters, but I would like to learn if it might be done without them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the ImageView and TextView - `tourImage`, `tourText` - are elements of `R.layout.tour_item_for_guide_info`.

If this is so, then when you reference it, you should use the `child` view to get them.

With other words, instead of:

```
ImageView tourImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tour_image);
TextView tourText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
```

You should have:

```
ImageView tourImage = (ImageView)child.findViewById(R.id.tour_image);
TextView tourText = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Not sure if this will definetly fix your problem, but it looks like a bug.

Comment: It is not my bug, it is my mistake. Thank you!